# How to call GDALDEMProcessing from the GDAL python wrapper?

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to calculate aspect and hillshade in python using GDAL. I have installed GDAL and GDAL.Native packages via NuGet but I could not find the GDALDEMProcessing calls (https://gdal.org/programs/gdaldem.html) for calculating aspect and hillshade of DEM file.

How to calculate aspect and hillshade in python using GDAL?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this particular functionnality of GDAL but is [this](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.DEMProcessing) what you're looking for?

As a general rule GDAL's documentation does not always exhaustively list the existing equivalent API calls for a CLI command. It is often a good thing to check [osgeo's documentation](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.html) directly, as that list of functions should be exhaustive (if a little scarce in explanations)